# comparison of the pointers in C

Tags: c

I have some simple question, when I do something like that:

```
int* ptr1
int* ptr2

if(ptr1 == ptr2)...
```

What do I actually compare:

```
1. addresses where ptr1 and ptr2 saved
2. addresses where content of pointers saved
```

If there is 1, how can I check 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That compares the pointer values, which are addresses.

So `ptr1==ptr2` tests whether the two pointers point to the same address -- your #2.

You could express #1 -- comparing the addresses of the pointers themselves -- with `&ptr1 == &ptr2`, but here you know that that will be false.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing wether ptr1 points to the same address as ptr2 does (and reciprocally). That means, your option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the actual pointers.

I am not sure from your phrasing what you actually want to do, but it is probably one of:

```
if (*ptr1 == *ptr2) ...
```

or

```
if (&ptr1 == &ptr2) ...
```

Comment: Your first case would compare the values they point to. Your second case compares their addresses and is **always false**. A good compiler will optimize it out at compile time. Two variables never have the same address.

Comment: Yes thanks, I know how pointers work. I found the original question to be a bit ambiguously phrased, but I agree my answer is a bit vague also. The OP likely wanted to do the first of my cases above.

Comment: I think OP wanted to do `if (ptr1 == ptr2)` i.e. check if they point to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To compare what the pointers actually point towards, use:

```
if(*ptr1 == *ptr2)...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
  int *ptr1;
```

you're defining a variable (that has an address) that points to an integer.  You can get the address of that variable by taking the address (&) of that variable, that is,

```
&ptr1
```

fundamentally, ptr1 will contain the address of a memory location (where an integer may be stored, if it point to a location where space has been allocated for such a thing).

Comparing the values of the ptr1 and ptr2 variables will tell you if they point at the same variable; comparing the dereferenced values of the ptr1 and ptr2 variables will tell you if the values they point at are the same.

Answer (score 0):

2) the values of the pointers and therefore the addresses they point to.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the values pointed to by the pointers:

1. check if any of the pointers are NULL
2. Figure out what both pointers being NULL means in context
3. compare with `if (*ptr1 == *ptr2)`

To compare the addresses where the pointers are stored use:

```
if ( &ptr1 == &ptr2 ) since these are the addresses of the pointers.
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use have something in the form "a==b" you are comparing the contents of variable a to the contents of variable b.  In the case that a and b are pointers, their contents are the addresses of some data so a==b will return true if they point to the same location and false otherwise.

To compare the addresses of two variables you need to do &a==&b.